# How to achieve @ManyToMany bi-directional association in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-rest

Currently, I'm learning Spring Data Rest, where I am having two Entities "Application" &  "Component" where both are having "@ManyToMany" associations present between them built using Spring Data Rest.

**Application Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "application")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Application {
---
---
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applications", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();

    //Helper methods
    public void addComponent(Component component) {
        components.add(component);
        component.getApplications().add(this);
    }
 
    public void removeComponent(Component component) {
        components.remove(component);
        component.getApplications().remove(this);
    }
}
```

**Component Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Component{
---
---
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "component_application", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "component_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "application_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();
}
```

while testing associated APIs, APIs associated with Component Entity (owner class) is working
**Component associated API**

```
curl -X PUT "https://ENVIRONMENT.com/components/1/applications" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d BODY_LIST
```

with body

```
https://ENVIRONMENT.com/applications/1
https://ENVIRONMENT.com/applications/12
```

But when I tried to create bi-directional associations from Application Entity (managed class) association APIs are not working, getting 204 for the PUT API call but nothing got associated when GET call is done.
**Application association API**

```
curl -X PUT "https://ENVIRONMENT.com/applications/1/component" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d BODY_LIST
```

with body

```
https://ENVIRONMENT.com/components/1
https://ENVIRONMENT.com/components/2
```

I tried adding custom add, remove methods in a managed class which is "Application Entity" here, still the same issue. Please let me know where I'm missing out.

Answer (score 0):

1 Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_book") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_author") })
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
 
    ...
}
```

2 Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
 
    ...
}
```

That’s all you need to do to define a bidirectional many-to-many association. You can now navigate it in both directions in your JPQL or Criteria API queries or on your domain objects.

```
b = em.find(Book.class, 1L);
List<Author> authors = b.getAuthors();
```

Bidirectional associations are easy to use in queries, but they also require an additional step when you persist a new entity.
You need to update the association on both sides when you add or remove an entity.
You can see an example of it in the following code snippet in which I first create a new Author entity and add the Book entity to the List of books.
And after that, I also need to add the new Author entity to the List of authors on the Book entity.

```
Book b = em.find(Book.class, 1L);
 
Author a = new Author();
a.setFirstName("Thorben");
a.setLastName("Janssen");
 
a.getBooks().add(b);
b.getAuthors().add(a);
 
em.persist(a);
```

Updating the associations on both entities is an error-prone task. It’s, therefore, a good practice to provide helper methods for it.

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
 
    public void addBook(Book b) {
        this.books.add(b);
        b.getAuthors().add(this);
    }
 
    public void removeBook(Book b) {
        this.books.remove(b);
        b.getAuthors().remove(this);
    }
 
    ...
}
```

see: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-many-association/

Comment: thanks for the response, I had added helper methods earlier in the "mappedBy" class (Application class), but as I said above the association APIs from Application to Component which is 
```
/applications/{id}/components
```
are not working (creating an association in Application for respective Component list) This is where I'm currently having an issue. Not sure what is being missed from my end.